# ASP.NET CSS Bundle Is Empty

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, styles, bundle

I'm trying a very simple bundle referencing one unminified css file.

```
Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/tsoCustom").Include("~/assets/css/custom.css"));
```

The styles tag is rendered to the page, however it is completely empty. Any ideas? I've tried all suggestions on stack and other sources with no luck.

```
<link href="/content/tsoCustom?v=I7zm5FPtpXRPPL0_d6tAHU54CiVjNjpsW3ivhtUGKVM1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Does your file exist in `~/assets/css/` directory with the name `custom.css` ?

Comment: Yes it does. Bear in mind I'm running localhost right now with EnableOptimizations = true. I have WebGrease 1.3.0.0 with System.Web.Optimization 1.1.0.0